# Bash script to write to unix socket and then read a response but ONLY AFTER the welcome message

Tags: bash, netcat, unix-socket, socat

I am connecting to a server that initiates an SSH tunnel for me so I can connect to a remote device.

I can do an interactive socat connexion and manually issue commands like this:

```
Connected to soundwave server v131 (welcome message)
tunnel r 7 localhost:22 (my command)
Attempting to initiate a tunnel session ID [55] on local port 30054. (response)
```

*The text in parenthesis is just my notes. They aren't actually part of the commands or responses.*

I know I can send a message to a unix socket using socat

```sh
echo "tunnel r 7 localhost:22" | socat UNIX-CONNECT:data/files/monitor.socket STDOUT
```

And I saw some posts about being able to write a command and read a command with socat.

But the software has limitations that it only listens for commands until after the welcome message is issued.

So, is there a way with socat, nc, or any other tool to connect to a unix socket automatically, read the welcome message, write the tunnel command, and then parse the response to get the port so I can open up an SSH session?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Use expect  https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect